# COUNT of rows with parent id equal to the row we have with a parent id of 0 in one query

Tags: mysql, hierarchy, tree

I'd like to do the following in one query using MySQL:

- grab a row that has a parent_id of 0
- grab a count of all the rows that have a parent_id of the row that we grabbed which has a parent_id of 0

How can I accomplish this in one query? **Please let me know if you need more information, I will *gladly* be as assistive as I can. I'm not an expert on creating questions so please tell me what more information you need.**

Here's an example of what I'm doing now:

```
select id from messages where parent_id=0
```

and then

```
select count(id) from messages where parent_id={{previously_chosen_id}}
```

How do I get a one shot query? Something like...

```
select id, count(records where parent_id=the id we just asked for)
```

**Or, is there a better way to handle this?** You see, currently I have to run a ton of queries to find the counts, when I'd rather do it in one shot.

Answer (score 8):

This is easily achievable with an in-line subquery :

```
select  m.id,
        (select count(*) from messages where parent_id= m.id ) as ChildCount
from messages m
where m.parent_id = 0
```

Note that no `group by` is needed because a sub-query is used.

Answer (score 3):

This query will give you the desired output:

```
SELECT
    parent.id
  , COUNT(child.id) AS child_count
FROM
             messages parent
  INNER JOIN messages child
    ON child.parent_id = parent.id
WHERE parent.parent_id = 0
GROUP BY parent.id;
```

You can see this code in action [here on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/039ee/6).

I have used a join in my solution, whereas druzin used a correlated subquery in his. Try both and see which runs faster in your environment. MySQL may reduce them to the same plan.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` in case category doesn't have subcategory.

```
     SELECT `parent`.`id`
          , `parent`.`name`
          , COUNT(`child`.`id`) AS `hasChild` 
       FROM `category` `parent` 
  LEFT JOIN `category` `child` 
         ON `parent`.`id` = `child`.`parent_id` 
      WHERE `parent`.`parent_id` = 3780 
   GROUP BY `parent`.`id`
```

Comment: How do you count child rows that comply with some condition? subquery?